# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded en next js v14

Tags: typescript, web, nextjs

Que puedo hacer, si en mi codigo no estoy usando ninfuna recursidad
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.